# Multiple rows and column checkboxes php

Tags: php

currently i have produced a set of checkbox based from database

It looks like

```
               Week 1        Week 2       Week 3       Week 4  .....
Student 1        []           []           []            []
Student 2        []            []          []            []
Student 3        []            []          []            [] 
Student 4        []            []          []            []
.....
```

[] represents checkbox

How do i get whatever ticked by user? I am using `attendance_list[]` as name for checkbox but however when one is ticked, it returns value for all users.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a **multi-dimensional array** to represent students and their attendance.

For example,

```
<!-- Student 1, Week 1 to 4 -->
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[1][1]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[1][2]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[1][3]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[1][4]' />


<!-- Student 2, Week 1 to 4 -->
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[2][1]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[2][2]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[2][3]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='attendance_list[2][4]' />

<!-- And, so on.. -->
```

Server side, you'll get an array of elements that have been checked. Using the indexes of the array, you can determine which student was in attendance during which weeks.

If all of the above checkboxes were checked, your array would look like so:

```
Array
(
    [attendance_list] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => on
                    [2] => on
                    [3] => on
                    [4] => on
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => on
                    [2] => on
                    [3] => on
                    [4] => on
                )

        )

)
```

This indicates that Student 1 and Student 2 were in attendance for all 4 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see your code, if that's alright. I'll guess at the answer for now.

When you use attendance_list[] as your name, PHP automatically assigns a different field in the POST for each checkbox as an array in the POST return.

If you want to differentiate the students, you can do this in the HTML by assigning the student_1[(#week)] as the name and 'Y' as the value when checked. On the server side, go through the POST by student and collect all the keys with a value of 'Y'. It should be there by default and the unchecked ones not come through, but I've encoutered odd behaviour before on this.

Josh went a step further and offered a multi-dimensional array. This will get you what you want if you're comfortable with sorting through multi-dimensional arrays.